# Call to undefined method whereHas() in laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.5

I am upgrading and refactoring my site to laravel 5.5, and this code is giving me a problem at the moment. I searched in the laravel github docs and didn't find any breaking changes that might affect this.

What I am trying to do is **Related To** section in my site, In every recipe page I want to display some more recipes that has the same category.

Here is my code:

```
    public static function getRelatedRecipes($recipe){

      $related_category_ids  = $recipe->category()->pluck('categories.id');

        return $relatedRecipes =
        Recipe::whereHas('categories', function ($q)use($related_category_ids){
        $q->whereIn('category_id', $related_category_ids);
        })
        ->where('id', '<>', $recipe->id)
        ->take(4)
        ->inRandomOrder()
        ->get();
}
```

This is the recipe model:

```
    <?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Recipe extends Model
{
    protected $guarded=[];

    /**
     * Get the route key name for Laravel.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getRouteKeyName()
    {
        return 'slug';
    }



    public function category()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Category');
    }

}
```

What could be the problem?

Thanks,

**P.S**

If any other code that you think is needed to resolve this, please tell me and I will post it here. :)

Comment: `Recipe` is not what you think it is, most likely.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy the recipe is what i think it is, and when i `dd($recipe)` i get the full recipe.

Comment: Show us your `Recipe` model.

Comment: Many to Many relationships had some breaking changes. Also what's the problem? As in what error you get?

Comment: @Eitan I didn't say `$recipe` isn't what you think it is. I said `Recipe` isn't what you think it is. What is the fully namespaced path to that class? What are the relationships inside of it/

Comment: @devk The error is `Call to undefined method whereHas()`.

Comment: @Marwelln I updated the question with the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all make sure, `Recipe` you use in the method is the model, so instead of

```
Recipe::whereHas('categories', function ($q)use($related_category_ids){
```

use

```
\App\Recipe::whereHas('categories', function ($q)use($related_category_ids){
```

The other thing is this `categories` relationship. In model you don't have `categories` relationship, you have only `category` relationship

Comment: Yup, its always "the little things". i didnt refactore well. i had to change ofcourse the categories to category. Works like a charm, as it should.